# Generate a variable Type of Array in the output method

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

The method : `Arrays.copyOfRange(arraySource, sourcePositionStart, sourcePositionStop)` allows us to clone `arraySource` with a specific startPosition and stopPosition.

It works with any type of array: `int[]`, `Integer[]`, `double[]`, `String[]`, ...

So my question is, how write a similar method, e.g. I want to write something like:

- `int[] newArray1 = customCloneArray(oldArray, 0, oldArray.length);`

So i tried this :

```
public static Object[] customCloneArray(
        Object[] source, int sourcePositionStart, int sourcePositionStop) {
    // We give the name of class of source like Double, String
    //Class theClass = (source instanceof Class? (Class)source: source.getClass());
    Object[] ouput = null;
    try {
        if(source instanceof String[]){
            ouput = (String[])Arrays.copyOfRange(source, sourcePositionStart, sourcePositionStop);
        }else if(source instanceof Integer[]){
            ouput = (Integer[])Arrays.copyOfRange(source, sourcePositionStart, sourcePositionStop);
        }else if(source instanceof Double[]){
            ouput = (Double[])Arrays.copyOfRange(source, sourcePositionStart, sourcePositionStop);
        }   
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ouput;
}
```

This works like this:

```
Integer[] newArray1 =  (Integer[]) customCloneArray(oldArray, 0, oldArray.length);

String[] newArray2 =  (String[]) customCloneArray(oldArray, 5, 10);
```

But I want to write this method in general way, for `int[]`, `double[]` ...

How can I do this?

Comment: `Arrays` has overloaded `copyOfRange` methods to handle arrays of primitive types, e.g. `int[]`, `double[]`, etc.  Other methods in that class also have overloaded methods for the same purpose.

Comment: You do like it's done in the `Arrays` class. Have overloaded methods that accept a `double[]`, an `int[]`, etc.

Comment: Are you asking about how to accept different types of parameters, or how to have a result object that has a variable type? The answer to the second one is Generics.

Comment: @ Engineer Dollery
Yes, This my question , i want to write something like this : 
int[] newArray = customCloneArray(OldArray, anIntegerStrat, anIntegerStop), which customCloneArray uses Arrays.copyOfRange((OldArray, anIntegerStrat, anIntegerStop).

i konw that i can directly write : int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange((OldArray, anIntegerStrat, anIntegerStop);

but i want to write a method that do the same thing.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The class `java.util.Arrays` has overloaded methods for primitives because they cannot be used with generics, or cast to objects.

Here are method signatures for `copyOf`. Each is a distinct and different method.

```
copyOf(boolean[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(char[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(double[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(float[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(long[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(short[] original, int newLength) 
copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)
```

Note that where the method requires padding of the array, they each pad with different values: `false`, `0` or `null` depending upon the type.

You may also wish to examine other primitive handling utility libraries, such as `Guava`, which has classes such as, for example:

```
com.google.common.primitives.Ints
com.google.common.primitives.Longs
```